# How do I use setInterval with my form to create an alarm clock?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to learn JavaScript and I've decided to make things more interesting by actually creating something instead of endless reading & no practice. I'm currently trying to build an alarm clock.

Here's my code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dCsax

```
function wakeup() {
    window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
}
```

I need to create another function that uses setInterval to check every few seconds if the time set in that form is equal to the current time, and if it is, execute the wakeup function that plays Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.

I don't know how to write this piece of code. Could someone please help me out so I can see how it's done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an id to your button, and on click set up the timer function as below:

```
 <input id="scheduleTimer" type="button" value="Schedule alarm"></input>


function getTimeoutSec() {
  var dt = new Date();
  var currSecs = dt.getSeconds() + (60 * dt.getMinutes()) + (60 * 60 * dt.getHours());

  var am_pm = document.getElementById('t').value;
  var formHour = parseInt(document.getElementById('h').value);
  if(am_pm == 'PM') {
    formHour += 12;
  }
  var formMin = parseInt(document.getElementById('m').value);
  var formSeconds = (formHour * 3600) + (formMin * 60);
  return formSeconds - currSecs;
}

window.onload = function() {
   var scheduleTimerButton = document.getElementById('scheduleTimer');
   scheduleTimerButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       var secRemaining = getTimeoutSec();
       setTimeout(wakeup, secRemaining * 1000);
   }, false);
};
```

**[Link to CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nAihK)**

Answer (score 2):

For a pure JS solution (no libraries) you should [read about Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

I've [forked your example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/niDqz) like this:

```
function set_alarm() {
  var h = document.getElementById('h').value;
  var m = document.getElementById('m').value;
  var t = document.getElementById('t').value;

  if ( t == 'PM' ) h+= 12;

  var now = new Date();
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(h);
  d.setMinutes(m);
  d.setSeconds(0);

  var delta = d.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (delta < 0) delta = -delta;

  setTimeout(wakeup,delta);
}
```

This should give you a hint about what to do.

You can also try using one of the many libraries about dates, expecially [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: +1 for using `setTimeout` instead of using `setInterval` and checking the date every second. In addition a `clearTimeout` could be used if the user only wants to have one alarm active instead of creating another alarm with every click to *Schedule alarm*.

Comment: @Keeper Hmm...am I missing something? Tried to run this on my localhost, I set an alarm, waited for an alert message back but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example function

```
function scheduleAlarm() {

var h = document.getElementById('h').value;
var m = document.getElementById('m').value;
var t = document.getElementById('t').value;


alert("Successfully scheduled alram!");
setInterval(function(){

  var date = new Date;

  var hours = date.getHours();  
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'

  if (h == hours && m == minutes && t == ampm){
    alert("Time to go to school, wake up!")
  }
  }, 5000); // will run every 5 seconds

}
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KcfgL)